# How can I set to do something when left clicked on a raw image?

Tags: c#, video, unity-game-engine, movie, render-to-texture

I've got multiple rawImage's in my scene, and each of the rawImage's are video which is movie Texture.

What I want to do is, when I left click the mouse button, only the clicked rawImage plays the video, but it seems that when I left click anywhere, all the video/movieTexture/rawImage play simultaneously.

---

```
public class video : MonoBehaviour {

    public MovieTexture movie;
    private AudioSource audio;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = movie as MovieTexture;
        audio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
        audio.clip = movie.audioClip;
        movie.Play ();
        audio.Play ();

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)&& movie.isPlaying)
            movie.Stop ();
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !movie.isPlaying)
            movie.Play ();  
    }

}
```

Comment: You should put the five initialisation rows into `Start()` and use colliders with raycasting to get wheather an object is clicked or not.

Comment: Do you have collision boxes on your videos?

Comment: AntiHeadshot - alright. How do I make the colliders with the raycasting?

Comment: Tom - My videos are from rawImage, so it doesn't have collider.

Comment: @Jack you should use `@AntiHeadshot`, then I will get a notification. I'm going to sleep, so i may take a look at sunday. Please let me know if you still ned help by sunday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing in your script is the check where the mouse clicked, we want to exclude all those videos that aren't under mouse when user presses it.

```
public class video : MonoBehaviour {

public MovieTexture movie;
private AudioSource audio;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = movie as MovieTexture;
    audio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
    audio.clip = movie.audioClip;
    movie.Play ();
    audio.Play ();

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        RectTransform r = transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>(); //Get's reference to RectTransform
        Vector3 size = new Vector3(r.rect.size.x * r.localScale.x, r.rect.size.y * r.localScale.y, 0); //Size in pixels (scale * default size)
        Vector3 pos = r.localPosition + new Vector3(Screen.width/2f, Screen.height/2f, 0)-size/2; //Position in pixels from the bottom-left corner of Image 
        //(r.localPosition is from the center of screen, that is why I substracted half of
        //the screen and minus half of size of the Image because r.localPosition anchor by default is in the center of Image
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        if (mousePos.x > pos.x && mousePos.x < pos.x + size.x && mousePos.y > pos.y && mousePos.y < pos.y + size.y) //This is basic logic of testing if point is inside rect
           if(movie.isPlaying) movie.Stop (); else movie.Play (); 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it works. Thankyou so much, but did you have any idea why all the video play together? did I need to called them differently in each script?

Comment: Yes, the problem was that each video played when MouseButtonDown was fired, wherever you clicked on screen so all of them started.